# Iterating over jsonb array: operator does not exist: name ->> unknown

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

In a game for Android users can login via Google+, Facebook, Twitter:

[image: app screenshot]

When the app connects to the PostgreSQL/PHP backend it sends a list of the social ids and I store them as `sid` column in the `social` table:

```
create table social (
        sid varchar(255) not null,
        auth char(32) not null,

        social integer not null check (0 <= social and social <= 6),
        given varchar(255) not null check (given ~ '\S'),
        photo varchar(255) null check (photo ~* '^https?://...'),

        stamp timestamp not null,
        ip inet not null,
        uid integer not null references users on delete cascade,
        primary key(sid, social)
);
```

In the other table called `users` I keep autoincremented user ids as `uid` column and use it to track their games, achievements, player stats:

```
create table users (
        uid serial primary key,

        created timestamp not null,
        stamp timestamp not null,

        banned_until timestamp null,
        banned_reason varchar(255) null
);
```

In the PHP login script I try to *merge* social accounts whenever possible -

by taking all received **sids**, finding the corresponding **uids** and then taking the *lowest* found **uid** and updating the records in the `social` table to use that lowest **uid**.

This already works well in PHP, but now I am trying to move the merging functionality into a PostgreSQL stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_users(
        IN in_users jsonb,
        IN in_ip inet,
        OUT out_uid integer) AS
$func$
DECLARE
        user jsonb;
BEGIN
        SELECT MIN(uid) INTO out_uid FROM social
        WHERE sid IN (SELECT u->>'sid' FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users) u);

        IF FOUND THEN
                UPDATE words_social SET uid=out_uid
                WHERE sid IN (SELECT u->>'sid' FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users) u);
        ELSE
                INSERT INTO words_users (created, stamp)
                VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
                RETURNING uid INTO out_uid;
        END IF;

        FOR user IN SELECT * FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users)
        LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'user sid = %', user->>'sid';

                UPDATE social SET
                        auth   = user->'auth',
                        social = user->'social',
                        given  = user->'given',
                        photo  = user->'photo',
                        stamp  = TO_TIMESTAMP(user->'stamp'),
                        ip     = in_ip,
                        uid    = out_uid
                WHERE sid = user->>'sid';

                IF NOT FOUND THEN
                        INSERT INTO social (
                                sid,
                                auth,
                                social,
                                given,
                                photo,
                                stamp,
                                ip,
                                uid
                        ) VALUES (
                                user->'sid',
                                user->'auth',
                                user->'social',
                                user->'given',
                                user->'photo',
                                TO_TIMESTAMP(user->'stamp'),
                                in_ip,
                                out_uid
                        );
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately, the above code prints the syntax error message:

```
# select * from merge_users(
'[{"sid":"12345284239407942","auth":"ddddc1808197a1161bc22dc307accccc","social":3,"given":"Alexander1","family":"Farber","photo":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/10154284239407942\/picture?type=large","place":"Bochum, Germany","female":0,"stamp":1450102770},{"sid":"54321284239407942","auth":"ddddc1808197a1161bc22dc307abbbbb","social":4,"given":"Alexander2","family":"Farber","photo":null,"place":"Bochum, Germany","female":0,"stamp":1450102800}]'::jsonb);

NOTICE:  min uid = <NULL>
ERROR:  operator does not exist: name ->> unknown
LINE 1: SELECT user->>'sid'
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT user->>'sid'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function words_merge_users(jsonb) line 15 at RAISE
```

I have tried appending `::jsonb` to `u` and `user` in the above code, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: This is crying out for [mcve] - we don't need to know that you're building a phone app to help you debug an error message in a single SQL query. We just need some sample data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have just tried to explain my stored procedure, hoping to receive more good PostgreSQL advises. If you copy-paste the 4 above statements into psql 9.5 prompt, you will get the error message I am struggling with - there is no additional data needed. I will try to prepare an SQL fiddle (their server does not work well for me) and update my question though.

Comment: A question on this site should be about one specific problem, not a general request for advice. If you're looking for general improvements, you might want to look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com If you want help debugging an error, your question should focus entirely on that error. I don't have PG9.5 to hand, and SQLFiddle only has 9.3, but your MCVE might be as short as this: https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/d411c4b303adfc426ec8

Comment: `user` is a keyword in ANSI SQL, in PostgreSQL it will always call the `current_user()` function, which returns the currently logged in user's name (which uses the system type `name`, hence the error).

Comment: @pozs Hah, I hadn't spotted that. Exactly the kind of error that trying to produce an MCVE might well have revealed.

Comment: Thank you that was it (combined with the sad fact, that I had 2 different stored functions `merge_users` with different parameters)